# Relationship between sources and binaries in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have source code tree that contains about 300 Makefiles. These Makefiles compile sources to object files and object files to several firmware images.

What I want is to get a listing like this:

```
<firmware image name> : <list of object files> : <list of source files>
```

Is there any tool for that?

Comment: I'm sure there is a set of shell magic (using grep and sed if nothing else) that could do it.  But to give advice we'd likely need to see what some of the makefile rules look like.  There isn't enough info above to go on.  But if you can't post the contents, think about running 'make -n' and parsing it's output.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if what you are shooting for is getting a list of images that will be built, you could try playing around with the `-n` and `-W` flags.

`-n` tells make to do a dry-run. It will print out all the commands it would have executed, but won't really execute them. If you do this after a `make clean` it might give you the information you want. Perhaps not in exactly the form you want, but that's what sed and awk are for.

`-W file` tells make to pretend that `file` was modified, and do its thing. This might be helpful if a `make clean` would be excessive.

Comment: The problem is that I can't launch make because it's special patched version of make running on separate build machine that i don't have access to

Comment: @Alexander, wait a minute. You can't run Make? You should have mentioned that in your question-- it changes the problem a lot. Can you modify the makefiles?

Comment: @Alexander - Does it produce logs when it runs? Perhaps you could use the output from those.

Comment: @Beta, yes I can modify makefiles, but can't run.

Answer (score 1):

Not by magic. Make doesn't know what are sources and what are objects. It just knows that there are all targets with various dependency relationships between them. You could try post-processing `-p`.

Comment: Looks like make -p can't handle Makefile dependencies.